# How to split a statement into multiple lines?

Tags: python, syntax, readability, code-readability

What would be the proper Pythonic way to break the first line of the below expression (to appear on multiple lines) so it can be more readable:

```
if props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == '' or props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == 'saml/simpleSAMLphp' and PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok":
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/simpleSAMLphp"
elif props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == 'saml/gsuite':
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/gsuite"
elif props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == 'saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp':
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp"
else:
     IDP_STRATEGY = "saml"
```

Comment: add `\\` (escape character) at every point before the new line.

Comment: I struggle sometimes too making stuff look readable, so I think this will be useful as reference once completely solved, for that reason please fix the indentation under else for future reference to others. I agree to other comments that assigning a variable for the reused property will enhance this code too.

Comment: I just figured that what your example code does is assigning the value of the "...idp.strategy" property as-is for most of the cases, are there more potential exceptions to being a value of "" or completely different values that you default to "saml" ? What do you want as a result if you have 'saml/simpleSAMLphp' but PROXYING_MECHANISM is not 'ngrok', because that would result in 'saml'

Comment: @dparolin: that's correct, I'm not doing the exhaustive check for all  possible permutations (for which, I guess, I'd need to use some parenthesis as well) but `saml` should be correct as a default in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this as per PEP8

```
if props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == '' \
        or props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == 'saml/simpleSAMLphp' \
        and PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok":
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/simpleSAMLphp"
elif props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == 'saml/gsuite':
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/gsuite"
elif props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy") == 'saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp':
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp"
else:
     IDP_STRATEGY = "saml"
```

Comment: Combining this with assigning a variable first for `props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy")` looks best to be, however there will always be arguably a disrupting look to it at the double indentation, but nothing really easy to fix.

Comment: You are showing PEP-8's second choice; implicit line continuation is preferred over explicit when it is available.

Answer (score 3):

## Refactor

I would start by not calling `props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy")` repeatedly. Call it once, and you immediately have less reason to split any lines.

```
strategy = props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy")
if not strategy or strategy == 'saml/simpleSAMLphp' and PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok":
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/simpleSAMLphp"
elif strategy == 'saml/gsuite':
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/gsuite"
elif strategy == 'saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp':
    IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp"
else:
     IDP_STRATEGY = "saml"
```

---

## Line continuation

For the first long line, your options are line continuation, either explicit:

```
if not strategy or \
   strategy == 'saml/simpleSAMLphp' and \
   PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok":
```

or implicit, inside parentheses:

```
if (not strategy or
    strategy == 'saml/simpleSAMLphp' and
    PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok"):
```

---

## Use lookup, not repeated comparisons

An even *better* option is to replace a long string of comparisons with a `dict` lookup:

```
strategies = {
    "saml/gsuite": "saml/gsuite",
    "saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp": "saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp",
}
if PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok":
    strategies['saml/simpleSAMLphp'] = 'saml/simpleSAMLphp'

IDP_STRATEGY = strategies.get(props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy"), "saml")
```

And because each key of the `dict` is just mapped to itself, you can replace *that* with a simple `set` lookup.

```
strategies = {
    "saml/gsuite",
    "saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp",
}
if PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok":
    strategies.add('saml/simpleSAMLphp')

IDP_STRATEGY = "saml"

strategy = props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy")
if strategy in strategies:
    IDP_STRATEGY = strategy
```

Take your pick which of the last two you find more readable. The `dict` is more redundant in its definition, but allows a single assignment to `IDP_STRATEGY`.

Comment: Great answer to the use-case the OP is trying to solve, not necessarily a perfect answer for other cases of line continuation that could arise, but those should be covered in other questions I presume, and my feeling is no one really comes here to solve theoretical problems when better practical solutions make them go away.

Answer (score 1):

```
prop_var = props.getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy")    
if prop_var == '' or prop_var == 'saml/simpleSAMLphp' and PROXYING_MECHANISM == "ngrok":
        IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/simpleSAMLphp"
    elif prop_var == 'saml/gsuite':
        IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/gsuite"
    elif prop_var == 'saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp':
        IDP_STRATEGY = "saml/remote-simpleSAMLphp"
    else:
         IDP_STRATEGY = "saml"
```

You add a `\` at the end of each line as stated in the comment. You can also replace each `getProperty("app.auth.idp.strategy")` with a variable so it's called once.

Answer (score 0):

You can either break it explicitly with '\' or break it by putting the condition inside a parentheses

```
if (a
    ==b
    ==c):
```

Comment: you can but don't. please follow D.S. Dhaliwal's answer based on pep8: break on `or`/`and`, don't split the tests whether you're using parentheses or not